# PHP Shell_exec not showing full output with Ghostscript

Tags: php, terminal, exec, shell-exec

I am making a script and need to know if a pdf-file contains colors.

I am working on a local linux server and have full access.

The terminal line of code that is working is:

```
gs -o - -sDEVICE=inkcov file.pdf
```

The output from the terminal is with a pdf that has been build up with only black is:

```
GPL Ghostscript 9.26 (2018-11-20)
Copyright (C) 2018 Artifex Software, Inc.  All rights reserved.
This software comes with NO WARRANTY: see the file PUBLIC for details.
Processing pages 1 through 1.
Page 1
 0.00000  0.00000  0.00000  0.12363 CMYK OK
```

Perfect so far. I am really happy with this output and need to get the last line back to my php-script.

What have I done:

```
function ink_coverage($file){
$file = str_replace(" ", "\ ", $file);
exec("gs -o - -sDEVICE=inkcov $file 2>&1",$output);
return $output;
}
$ink = ink_coverage($file);
echo 'ink = ' .$ink[5];
```

Another way I have tried using shell_exec:

```
function ink_coverage($file){
$file = str_replace(" ", "\ ", $file);
$output = shell_exec("gs -o - -sDEVICE=inkcov $file");
return $output;
}
    $ink = ink_coverage($file);
    echo 'ink = ' .$ink;
```

The output is always only the first three lines:

```
GPL Ghostscript 9.26 (2018-11-20) Copyright (C) 2018 Artifex Software, Inc. All rights reserved. This software comes with NO WARRANTY: see the file PUBLIC for details.
```

After a search on stackoverflow and google I have found a suggestion to add 2>&1
So for example I have also tried this with exec and shell_exec:

```
exec("gs -o - -sDEVICE=inkcov $file 2>&1",$output);
```

After adding this (2>&1) the output is still only the first three lines from the terminal output.

Is there anyone who can help me think in the right direction towards a solution.

Comment: I'm not sure why the above is not working. But an alternative to shell_exec could be to use `system()` and `ob_get_clean()` to return the contents of the output buffer.

Comment: I always steer people towards [`proc_open`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.proc-open.php) which separates stdout and stderr for easier reading, and also gives you access to `cod` and environment variables if needed

Answer (score 0):

Message

```
Processing pages 1 through 1.
Page 1
 0.00000 0.00000 0.12363 CMYK OK
```

it is sent much later and not as ghostscript therefore php does not receive it. But it will be more convenient for you to use ghostscript for php

[Documentation](https://heiglandreas.github.io/Org_Heigl_Ghostscript/)

[Github link](https://github.com/heiglandreas/Org_Heigl_Ghostscript)

Example:

```
<?php
use Org_Heigl\Ghostscript\Ghostscript;

// Create the Ghostscript-Wrapper
$gs = new Ghostscript ();

// Set the output-device
$gs->setDevice('jpeg')
// Set the input file
   ->setInputFile('path/to/my/ps/or/pdf/file')
// Set the output file that will be created in the same directory as the input
   ->setOutputFile('output')
// Set the resolution to 96 pixel per inch
   ->setResolution(96)
// Set Text-antialiasing to the highest level
   ->setTextAntiAliasing(Ghostscript::ANTIALIASING_HIGH);
// Set the jpeg-quality to 100 (This is device-dependent!)
   ->getDevice()->setQuality(100);
// convert the input file to an image
if (true === $gs->render()) {
    echo 'success';
} else {
    echo 'some error occured';
}
?>
```